How to center the ticks between grid lines in Radar chart?
The problem is that I don't know how to position the ticks (numbers from 1 to 5) between the grid lines. Currently it is showing above the grid lines:

Here is the javascript code:
const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "radar",
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange", "Turquesa"],
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [4, 3.5, 2, 5, 4.5, 4, 2],
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: "#ECAE4880",
        borderColor: "#FBDDAD",
        color: "#f00"
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    elements: {
      point: {
        pointStyle: false
      }
    },
    scales: {
      r: {
        min: 0,
        max: 5,
        backgroundColor: "#FDF7EC",
        ticks: {
          backdropPadding: {
            x: 16,
            y: 16
          },
          z: 10,
          backdropColor: "transparent",
          color: "red",
          backgroundColor: "black",
          stepSize: 1
        },
        grid: {
          color: "#EA910B",
          backgroundColor: "red"
        },
        angleLines: {
          color: "transparent",
          // borderDash: 0
        }
        // angleLines: {
        //   display: false
        // },
        // suggestedMin: 50,
        // suggestedMax: 100
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
      title: {
        display: false
      },
      subtitle: {
        display: false
      }
    }
  }
  // plugins: [
  //   {
  //     id: "centerTick",
  //     afterDraw: (chart, args, opts) => {
  //       const { ctx } = chart;
  //       ctx.fillStyle = opts.color || Chart.defaults.color;
  //       ctx.fillText(
  //         chart.scales.r.min,
  //         chart.scales.r.xCenter -
  //           ctx.measureText(chart.scales.r.min).width / 2,
  //         chart.scales.r.yCenter
  //       );
  //     }
  //   }
  // ]
});


Here is the link to code: https://codepen.io/luaneaquino/pen/qBzaEOL
I tried setting plugin (commented code), but it does not work:
// plugins: [
  //   {
  //     id: "centerTick",
  //     afterDraw: (chart, args, opts) => {
  //       const { ctx } = chart;
  //       ctx.fillStyle = opts.color || Chart.defaults.color;
  //       ctx.fillText(
  //         chart.scales.r.min,
  //         chart.scales.r.xCenter -
  //           ctx.measureText(chart.scales.r.min).width / 2,
  //         chart.scales.r.yCenter
  //       );
  //     }
  //   }
  // ]

I expect the ticks be like this image below:


I also tried using the plugin to redraw the label in the new position, but the label would have a weird tiny offset, so I simply added a tiny offset to the result to correct this error.


 const ctx = document.getElementById('radarChart').getContext('2d');

        const data = {
            labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'My First Dataset',
                data: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2],
                fill: true,
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(255, 159, 64)',
                pointBackgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 159, 64)',
                pointBorderColor: '#fff',
                pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
                pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgb(255, 159, 64)'
            }]
        };

        const options = {
            scales: {
                r: {
                    angleLines: {
                        display: true
                    },
                    suggestedMin: 0,
                    suggestedMax: 5,
                    ticks: {
                        stepSize: 1,
                        showLabelBackdrop: false,
                        display: false
                    },
                    grid: {
                        circular: true
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        const radarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'radar',
            data: data,
            options: options,
            plugins: [{
                id: 'customTicks',
                afterDraw(chart) {
                    const ctx = chart.ctx;
                    const scale = chart.scales.r;
                    ctx.save();
                    ctx.translate(chart.width / 2, chart.height / 2);
                    ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.font.size, Chart.defaults.font.style, Chart.defaults.font.family);
                    ctx.fillStyle = Chart.defaults.color;

                    const tickValues = scale.ticks.map(t => t.value);
                    const tickSpacing = scale.drawingArea / (tickValues.length-1);

                    tickValues.forEach((value, index) => {
                        if (value % 1 === 0 && value !== 0) {
                            const radius = tickSpacing * index;
                            const angleRadians = (Math.PI / 2);
                            const x = radius * Math.cos(angleRadians);
                            const y = tickSpacing - radius * Math.sin(angleRadians);
                            ctx.fillText(value, x-4, y-13);
                        }
                    });

                    ctx.restore();
                }
            }]
        });
*{margin:0}
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="radarChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>



